# Python csv library writes dots instead of actual array

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to write in csv file 3 columns. One with a number, one with a purpose (training/testing) and the third one with a `numpy` array.

I tried this code

```py
with open('resources/new_file.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    row_writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for i, row in enumerate(data):
        image = np.fromstring(row, dtype='uint8', sep=' ')
        image = np.reshape(image, (48, 48))
        x_train[i] = image
        img = image
        face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
        faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(img, 1.1, 2)
        for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
            new_img = cv2.resize(img[y: y + h, x:x + w], dsize=(48, 48), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
            image_str = new_img.flatten()
            row_writer.writerow([emotion[i], purpose[i], image_str])
csvfile.close()
```

but after opening the csv file every row is like that (exactly like that with the `...`)

```
3,Training,[ 49  72  85 ... 192 188 185]
```

Also notice that between some numbers, there is a double space.

How can i write the whole thing to be like

```
3,Training,49 72 85 12 0 [here every other number from array] 192 188 185
```

Comment: Right after `image_str = new_img.flatten()`, please add `print(image_str)`; what does that give you?

Comment: `' '.join(map(str,image_str))`?

Comment: Yes, because `image_str` is a `numpy.ndarray`, and then you simply write the string representation of the array

Comment: @wwii that was it. If you post your comment as an answer, I could set it as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

To get every number that you have in array, you can try setting

```
import sys
import numpy
numpy.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)
```

I think double spaces are because to account the 3 digit numbers also present in that array because you used flatten. If not used flatten then in truncated form it shows with spaces to account for readability.